# How can I use indexOf() to check if a string in my array partially matches a string in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, substring, indexof

I have a function that filters a table for specific items. In my application I have numerous tables many with different filters so I wrote a function that can filter the table with dynamic data. Some of the filters use inputs where the user has to type in their query. If the user's query only partially matches a string in one of the table arrays the table doesn't return the expected results.

E.g.

```
filterArr = [null, null, "246", null]
TableFilter = [
    {"name": Matthew Shapiro", "claim_number":"2469135-6", "type": "Medical", "date": "05/04/2018", "doctor": "John Smith", "hospital": "University Hospital"},
    {"name": "John Connor", "claim_number": "1352460-2", "type": "Medical", "date": "01/01/2018", "doctor": "John Smith", "hospital": "University Hospital"},
    {"name": "Sam Heist", "claim_number": "1270120-9", "type": "Medical", "date": "02/11/2018", "doctor": "William Rodgers", "hospital":  "Springfield Hospital"}
]
```

In this example the table wouldn't return the first two rows even though 246 can be found in "2469135-6" and "1352460-2". If I updated the query in the filter to the full string of either number it would.

How can I update my function to return the appropriate TableFilters if a string in filterArr partially matches a string in TableFilter[i]?

Below is my function as well as a screenshot of one of my tables.

```
let rowArr = []
let filteredResults = []

this.rows.map(element => {
    rowArr = Object.values(element); // Object.values of each row
    rowArr.filter(e => { 
        if (rowArr.indexOf(filterArr) !== -1) {
            // check for substring match. Currently not working
            console.log('match');
        }

        if (filterArr.includes(e)) { // check if filter has value that matches row
            filteredResults.push(element);
            this.rows = filteredResults;
        }
    })
})
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind contriving a runnable code using code snippet to reproduce your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to *filter* your TableFilter array for rows where *some* of the fields values contain *some* of filterArray's values.

```js
var filterArr = [null, null, "246", null];
var TableFilter = [
{"name": "Matthew Shapiro", "claim_number":"2469135-6", "type": "Medical", "date": "05/04/2018", "doctor": "John Smith", "hospital": "University Hospital"},
{"name": "John Connor", "claim_number": "1352460-2", "type": "Medical", "date": "01/01/2018", "doctor": "John Smith", "hospital": "University Hospital"},
{"name": "Sam Heist", "claim_number": "1270120-9", "type": "Medical", "date": "02/11/2018", "doctor": "William Rodgers", "hospital":  "Springfield Hospital"}
];

var foundResults = TableFilter.filter(row => {
  return Object.keys(row).some(fieldName => {
    return filterArr.some(filt => {
      return row[fieldName].indexOf(filt) > -1;
    });
  });
});

console.log(foundResults);
```

Comment: James thanks for your response, but I'm having trouble integrating your code into mine. Also, I noticed you nested the rows into another array. So the original table rows are in an array of objects and I map over them and push them into an array. I'm not sure how to change the structure the way you wrote it here.

Comment: Hello!  I just took your example and modified it.  (I did change the definition of TableFilter but it doesn't affect the structure).  You say you have an array of objects, can you include its definition in your question please?

Comment: I see. This is my fault. My original table is an array of Objects. I used .map() to convert it to an array. I'll update my question.

Comment: I see your edit but that’s not valid, objects have properties ie name value pairs, you only have values.

Comment: Anyway I updated my answer to work with TableFilter being an array of objects.

Comment: You're right. I updated my post. Sorry for the sloppy code. I was trying to condense it. Unfortunately, your function is returning an error. "ERROR TypeError: row[fieldName].indexOf is not a function." I also noticed that the second two returns don't return anything when I try to log them in the console.